# Get variable list from a list (using Linq ?)

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there any way of reducing this getter to about one line using something like linq? I did a search and didn't find anything. Just curious.

```
private List<UserItem> userItems
{ 
    get 
    { 
        List<UserItem> list = new List<UserItem>();

        foreach (var item in items) {
            list.Add(item.UserItem);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you always create a new list?

Comment: `List<UserItem> list = new List<UserItem>();` - don't repeat yourself. this is not java for God's sake. use `var`.

Comment: @HighCore 
var list = new List<UserItem>();
Like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

```
get {
    return items.Select(x => x.UserItem).ToList();
}
```

MSDN Link for `Select`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, it projects what you want into a new list. In the above example, we are projecting each `UserItem` property of the objects in your `items` collection into a list.

EDIT:

8 years later... its possible to simplify it further now that properties can be expression bodies.

```
private List<UserItem> UserItems => items.Select(x => x.UserItem).Tolist();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutely what I wanted. Cheers :)

Comment: Can be simplified even further with 

`private List<UserItem> UserItems => items.Select(x => x.UserItem).Tolist();`

Comment: @EmotionTheory 8 years later... yes, that is now possible. I've added it as an edit :)